# Can this quadratic formula of inner products be simplified

Tags: geometry, vectors

We let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be the inner product between two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can the following be simplified:

$\langle\textbf{x}_c - \textbf{x}_i, \textbf{n}\rangle \pm \sqrt{\langle\textbf{n}, \textbf{x}_c\rangle^2 - 2\langle\textbf{n}, \textbf{x}_c\rangle\langle\textbf{n}, \textbf{x}_i\rangle + \langle\textbf{n}, \textbf{x}_i\rangle^2 + 2\langle\textbf{x}_i, \textbf{x}_c\rangle + \langle\textbf{r}_c, \textbf{r}_c\rangle - \langle\textbf{x}_i, \textbf{x}_i\rangle - \langle\textbf{x}_c, \textbf{x}_c\rangle}$

I am trying to simplify this expression but this is the best I can do so far. Is there any further simplifications that can be made?

$\textbf{EDIT}:$ After some comments I now have the following:

$\langle\textbf{x}_c - \textbf{x}_i, \textbf{n}\rangle \pm \sqrt{\langle\textbf{n}, \textbf{x}_c - \textbf{x}_i\rangle^2 -\langle\textbf{x}_c - \textbf{x}_i, \textbf{x}_c - \textbf{x}_i\rangle + \langle\textbf{r}_c, \textbf{r}_c\rangle}$

Is there any geometric/intuitive way to interpret this expression?

Comment: The first three terms under the radical sign are $$\langle n, x_c\rangle^2 - 2\langle n, x_c\rangle\langle n, x_i\rangle + \langle n, x_i\rangle^2 \\= (\langle n, x_c\rangle - \langle n, x_i\rangle)^2 \\= \langle n, x_c-x_i\rangle^2.$$ Similarly there are three other terms which simplify to $-\langle x_c-x_i, x_c-x_i\rangle$.

Comment: I do not follow how you got $- \langle x_c - x_i, x_c - x_i\rangle$

Comment: Try expanding it and see.

Comment: Yes I just figured it out thanks! Mind checking the edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_c, x_i, r_c, n \in \mathbb{R}^N$, then
$$\langle x_c - x_i , n \rangle \pm \sqrt{ \langle n, x_c - x_i \rangle^2 + \langle r_c , r_c \rangle - \langle x_c - x_i , x_c - x_i \rangle }$$
describes the distance between $x_i$ and the point where a line starting at $x_i$, direction unit vector $n$, intersects a ($N-1$)-sphere centered at $x_c$ with radius $r_c$ .

It is much easier to recognize, if you switch to traditional vector algebra notation,
$$\left( \vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i \right) \cdot \hat{n} \pm \sqrt{ \left ( \hat{n} \cdot \left ( \vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i \right ) \right )^2 + r_c^2 - \left ( \vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i \right ) \cdot \left ( \vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i \right ) }$$

Although ordinarily $r_c$ is a scalar, it can just as well be a vector, above. (I.e., any vector from the center of the sphere to any point on its surface.)

Comment: Thank you for shedding light on this. Vector algebra notation did make it easier to see.

Comment: @David: Years ago, I collected similar equations wrt. cylinders with no end caps, flat end caps, or round end caps (spheres, obviously) to my [wikipedia user page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Nominal_animal), but with the assumption that $x_i = 0$, to be used in raycasting. (Since the world typically is transformed anyway, moving the camera/eye to origin does simplify the initial ray intersection calculations, so assuming $x_i = 0$ is a kind of an useful optimization.)

Comment: This is great @Nominal Animal! I currently am working with ray intersections in a union of spheres geometry (such as molecules).

Comment: @David: Interesting! I do recommend rotating and translating the world so that the camera is at origin, looking along say positive $z$ axis, as it makes the math much easier. For example, you can treat the view frustum as a cone, to trivially exclude spheres not in view. For publication-quality molecular models, I worked out how to approximate the outlines and intersections using vector elements; with the idea of using a raytraced/cel-shaded image beneath, and a vector image on top, for lightweight but high quality images. Feel free to email me if you wish to discuss nitty-gritty details. :)

Comment: @Nominal_Animal: It seems that this equation finds all intersections when you span the direction vector in both directions. However, is there a way to modify this so that it only finds intersections with spheres that are in the direction of $\hat{n}$ and not also $-\hat{n}$?

Comment: @David: If $$\hat{n} \cdot \left ( \vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i \right ) \gt 0$$ then the sphere is in the direction $\hat{n}$ and not $-\hat{n}$. Alternatively, if you consider the signed distance $d$, $$d = (\vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i) \cdot \hat{n} \pm \sqrt{ (\hat{n} \cdot (\vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i))^2 + r_c^2 - (\vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i)\cdot(\vec{x}_c - \vec{x}_i)}$$ then $d \gt 0$ are in the $+\hat{n}$ half-space, and $d \lt 0$ are in the $-\hat{n}$ half-space. This means that if you only consider intersections where $d \gt 0$, they are in direction $+\hat{n}$ (and not $-\hat{n}$).

Comment: (Remember, the intersection is at $\vec{x}_i + d \hat{n}$.)

Comment: I thought that the $\pm$ represented the two intersections of the same sphere (the entry and exit point of that sphere)?

Comment: Wait, disregard above comment. I misunderstood your response. Thanks for the help...again!

Comment: @David: No worries! For others reading these comments, the confusion was because $d$ can have two values, as a non-tangential $\hat{n}$ intersects the spherical shell twice. The *rule* is that (no matter which $d$ you choose,) $d \gt 0$ is in the same direction as $\hat{n}$, and $d \lt 0$ is in the opposite direction ($-\hat{n}$).